# PayPal no longer redirecting to my website after someone makes a purchase?

Tags: paypal

I've not changed any settings in my PayPal account for years. It's always said something along the lines of "You will be redirected to the merchant in 10 seconds. If this doesn't work, please click here".

It **still** says that, but now instead of (a) redirecting, or (b) staying on that screen [enabling the users to click the link for a manual redirect] it instead goes to a new screen with nothing but my logo and the PayPal logo and this text:

"Your payment has been completed. To continue shopping, please return to the merchant." (just text, there's no link to click)

Has anyone else experienced this? Is it a temporary glitch with PayPal, or have they changed something for some reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're using a input called "ReturnURL" in your button.

Change "ReturnURL" to "return" and it should work.

Comment: I actually wasn't specifying a return at all in my encrypted button.  I never have before and it's always worked, using the URL set out in my PayPal account online instead.  I've now added it, and it now works again, thank you.  They've obviously changed something at their end, but so long as it works again I'm happy enough!